# Convergence radius of complex series

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the radius of convergence of the following series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(z+2)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^34^n}}$$
I expanded the series and found that I get the result if I use the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(z+2)^n}{(n+2)^34^{n+1}}}$$
Then, with the root test, I got
$$R=\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\frac{1}{(a_n)^{1/n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}{(n+2)^{3/n}4^{1+1/n}}=4$$
Is this correct, or is it wrong if I rewrite the first series as the second one?

Comment: What you used is the root test. But it is correct and the ratio test would work as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I corrected it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It is completely right, and very good idea to change the index $\;n-1\to n\;$ . Makes things clearer and easier to grasp. The test you used is based on the $\;n\,$- th root test, and it is called Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem (or Formula) , though this last in fact is more powerful as it uses originally the $\;\limsup\;$ .

Comment: More generally, changing the index on a power series is not going to affect the radius of convergence (if done correctly). The index variable is merely a notational device. It is not integral to the series itself. As you noticed, both your version and the original result in the exact same terms when written out. The radius of convergence is a property of the series itself, not of the notation used to express it.